# how to change border background when textblock text changes

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8

i have a bound textblock(say mre than 6) in longlistselector following with a border. the border apply for all textblocks. here is the bound code:

```vb
Public Sub LoadData()
    ' Sample data; replace with real data
    Me.Items.Add(New ItemViewModel() With {.LineTwo = "New Endowment Plans", .LineThree = ""})
    Me.imgsource.Add(New ItemViewModel() With {.imgsource = "/Images/endow_1.jpg"})
    Me.Items.Add(New ItemViewModel() With {.LineTwo = "New Money Back Plans", .LineThree = ""})
    Me.Items.Add(New ItemViewModel() With {.LineTwo = "Single Premium Plans"})
    Me.Items.Add(New ItemViewModel() With {.LineTwo = "New Term", .LineThree = "Plans"})
    Me.Items.Add(New ItemViewModel() With {.LineTwo = "New Health", .LineThree = "Plans"})
    Me.Items.Add(New ItemViewModel() With {.LineTwo = "New Pension", .LineThree = "Plans"})
    Me.Items.Add(New ItemViewModel() With {.LineTwo = "Withdrawl", .LineThree = "Plans"})
    Me.Items.Add(New ItemViewModel() With {.LineTwo = "Plans", .LineThree = "Information"})
End Sub
```

and here is xaml code:

```
<phone:LongListSelector>
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,2,0,4" Height="105" Width="432" Tap="StackPanel_Tap">
                <Border x:Name="planImage" BorderThickness="5" Width="99" Height="99" BorderBrush="#FFFFC700">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/liclogo.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <StackPanel Width="311" Margin="8,-7,0,0">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Plantype" Foreground="#FF8FF01B" Text="{Binding LineTwo }"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#FF8FF01B" Text="{Binding LineThree }" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,-2,10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

i want to change each  border background images because one i was using reflected same in all textblocks.

Comment: You mean `background` of the window or TextBlock?

Comment: @PrincePandey can you explain what you mean by _I want to change each Border background images because one I was using change all border's images as same_? When background image should change?

Comment: @dkozl i have edited my original post. please check again.

Comment: @Kulasangar I mean background of the border.

Comment: How do you want to change the border?  When an items is selected in the LongListSelector?

Comment: @Walt Ritscher I want to change border when items loaded. Say change border with items loaded in textblock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you would like here is to have a different image for each item in your list.

There are two ways to achieve that.

**Option 1:**
Add a new property (Like you have LineTwo and LineThree) with name `ImagePath` for example and add the image path for each item separately and then change code to:

```
<Border.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Border.Background>
```

**Option 2:**
Create a converter and bind it to the image source of your `Image` element.
Examples:
Image Example [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-25-Advanced-Binding-with-Value-Converters)
Visibility Example [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Collection_of_Value_converters_for_Windows_Phone_apps)
Microsoft's getting started example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter)

---

I think the best solution for your case is to use **Option 1**. Straight forward and does not need any additional processing. However this would require for you to have that extra field with the path which one could disagree about since it keep a lot of "useless" information for static image paths and would recommend going with **Option 2**!

Comment: funny.. it's work. thanks.. 
my final code:
Me.Items.Add(New ItemViewModel() With {.LineOne = "/Images/endow_1.jpg", .LineTwo = "New Endowment Plans", .LineThree = ""})

and in xaml:

 <Border x:Name="planImage" BorderThickness="5" Width="99" Height="99"  BorderBrush="#FFFFC700">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=LineOne  }" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                </Border>

thanks.